# How can I remove pagebreaks from Microsoft Word?

Tags: ms-word

Word documents are split into pages by default. How do I remove the page breaks and make my document 1 continuous page?

Example of a page break (circle 1):

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Depends on what you exactly mean:

-If you don't want page breaks to appear on the screen, select "View" --> "Web Layout".
Page breaks do still exist, but you don't see them anymore.

-If you want to 'delete' all "manual page breaks" in a document (page breaks usually added by hitting "Ctrl+Enter"), replace "^12" with "" (empty string).

So, hit Ctrl+H, at "Find what" type ^12, leave "Replace with" empty, and then hit "Replace all".

Comment: Good info! The problem with the Web Layout is that it allows lines to be as long as the window is wide, which is less readable. When I am using word, it's almost never to print things out, and I just want the page breaks to go away to make the document easier to read in electronic format. Federico's answer below is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 27):

If you want a continuous print view , you can double click in the space between the two pages, the space between pages change to a line in all the document.

Comment: Or, depending on what you're doing, you may find Draft View useful (View > Draft). Aside from page breaks, Word can insert other objects between pages, such as headers and footers, which can also get in the way. To quote the tooltip: "Draft View // Switch your view to see just the text in your document. // This is useful for quick editing because headers/footers and certain objects won't show up, allowing you to focus on your text."